# error message when installing elementary 6

Tags: system-installation

It is telling me that:

[image]

Any ideas, please?

Comment: This is a normal message. If the USB stick is 1.1 or 2.0, it may take a while (minutes or hours). If the USB stick is bad (or very cheap), this may take a little longer. The objective here is to ensure the integrity of the installation media.

Comment: Thank you - I am not having very good time right now with my NAS mapping problem (windows 5 seconds, Linux two days and counting...) so I am paranoid about any error messages. I will get another stick and try again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that it is indeed "a normal message" as per comment from @matigo
the problem is solved and can be closed (my installation went OK BTW)